# How to manipulate Create, Update, Delete and Search Contact on Salesforce in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, salesforce

I have to integrate Salesforce in ASP .NET app Using REST API. Currently I have to perform operation on Contacts on Salesforce like insert, update, delete, search and bulk upload. How to perform these operations?

Comment: There are so many examples if you search google.  What is it about those examples that have failed you?

Comment: Pls share links then.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Force.com_for_ASP.NET_Developers](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_for_ASP.NET_Developers)

Opens source API for .NET has been released: [Salesforce-API-for-NET-released-Open-Source](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/NET-Development/Salesforce-API-for-NET-released-Open-Source/td-p/128530).

Comment: I want to use REST API. Currently I have followed Dan's blog, it's useful but I couldn't manipulate contacts till yet.

Comment: @Agile, That comment shows just how lacking your question really is.  You dont mention REST at all and you say that you've got some things in place already.  Narrow down your question to a specific problem and you'll get a much better response. (+1 Arun :)

Comment: Link only answers are not encouraged, could you please elaborate before your answer gets converted to a comment? **How** do the links help the user?